# Running gdb while passing in a file from standard input c

Tags: c

So, when I run my program, I do

```
./a.out < SampleData
```

How would I debug my program while still being able to pass in the SampleData file?

Thanks

Edited: I tried doing

```
gdb ./a.out
run < SampleData
```

when I do it, it runs my program, outputs what it normally outputs, then leaves me with:

"[Inferior 1 (process 19460) exited with code 03]"

What?

Answer (score 6):

You can also do the redirection inside of gdb.

```
gdb a.out
# ...
(gdb) run < SampleData
```

EDIT based on update:

This text:

```
[Inferior 1 (process 19460) exited with code 03]
```

is a message from `gdb` itself. Inferior is the name given to a process being debugged by `gdb`.  Here, there is only 1 (but there can be more than one). The exit code is the code your program terminated with.  If your `main()` function completed, it's the value that it returned.  If you called `exit()`, it's the value you passed.  These values are often useful for passing information about if your program succeeded or failed back to the caller (such as a shell).

I'd suggest checking `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` in C (which indicate a successful/failed run respectively). Many programs define additional exit codes to indicate specific errors.

Since the value here is `03`, which is an unusual exit code, I'd suggest maybe your `main()` is missing a return statement at the end?

Comment: `main` is a special case function where if no `return` is specified, the function returns 0 (or the equivalent of `exit(0)` happens or some such equivalent, I can't remember which). This was introduced in C99 I think.

Comment: @dreamlax Yeah, it's kind of an odd exception but it's only in C99 and onward. Could also be that the code wrongly defined `main()` to return `void`.

Answer (score 1):

```
gdb --args ./a.out < SampleData
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `run` command in GDB, you can use the normal input redirection:

```
$ gdb ./a.out
(gdb) run < SampleData
```